# How do I use alsa from x86 chroot on respberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, alsa, chroot, i386

I managed to setup x86 debian stretch in chroot with qemu i386 static and binfmt on my raspberry pi 3b stretch, now I want to use alsa in the chroot (do not want pulse audio) environment however keep getting

```
$ aplay -l
Unsupported ioctl: cmd=0x81785501
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

sound card appears to be visible in the chroot

```
$cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
```

The soundcard is functional in regular pi environment and returns list as expected

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

user in the chroot is the same name and is part of all the groups as regular user, also following folders are mounted between the environemnts:

```
sys
proc
/dev
/dev/pts
/dev/shm
/home/user
```

below is the strace for aplay - l in chroot, not that I have trimmed quite some cacheflush and rt_sigprocmask

```
1739  execve("/usr/bin/aplay", ["aplay", "-l"], [/* 11 vars */] <unfinished ...>
1739  uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
1739  brk(NULL)                         = 0x63207000
1739  brk(0x63207d58)                   = 0x63207d58
1739  set_tls(0x632074c0, 0x602b162c, 0, 0x602c4f8c, 0x4) = 0
1739  set_tid_address(0x63207068)       = 1739
1739  set_robust_list(0x63207070, 12)   = 0
1739  ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
1739  readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/qemu-i386-static", 4096) = 25
1739  brk(0x63228d58)                   = 0x63228d58
1739  brk(0x63229000)                   = 0x63229000
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  clone(child_stack=0xb6fdbde8, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0xb6fdc318, tls=0xb6fdc770, child_tidptr=0xb6fdc318) = 1741
1741  set_robust_list(0xb6fdc320, 12 <unfinished ...>
1741  <... set_robust_list resumed> )   = 0
1741  nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=10000000},  <unfinished ...>
1739  gettimeofday({tv_sec=1582165215, tv_usec=910982}, NULL) = 0
1739  prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
1739  gettimeofday({tv_sec=1582165215, tv_usec=911591}, NULL) = 0
1739  open("/etc/qemu-binfmt/i386", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
1739  madvise(0x602dd740, 16771264, MADV_HUGEPAGE) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
1739  open("/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
1739  fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
1739  read(4, "4096\n", 1024)           = 5
1739  close(4)                          = 0
1739  gettid()                          = 1739
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=62916, ...}) = 0
1739  geteuid32()                       = 1000
1739  getegid32()                       = 1000
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0!\222\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  brk(0x6324b000)                   = 0x6324b000
1739  open("/lib/ld-linux.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0 \n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 1024) = 1024
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  getuid32()                        = 1000
1739  geteuid32()                       = 1000
1739  getgid32()                        = 1000
1739  getegid32()                       = 1000
1741  <... nanosleep resumed> 0xb6fdbc7c) = 0
1741  futex(0x612e3648, FUTEX_WAIT, 4294967295, NULL <unfinished ...>
1739  uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24702, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@\30\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30692, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\260\341\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1189404, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\340F\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=341556, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0000\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13860, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\340O\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=132328, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\0\204\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
1739  fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1791908, ...}) = 0
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  munmap(0x40839000, 28672)         = 0
1739  set_tid_address(0x40b9e768)       = 1739
1739  prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
1739  uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
1739  munmap(0xb5f8d000, 135168)        = 0
1739  ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/snd/controlC0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1739  fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)   = 0
1739  write(2, "Unsupported ioctl: cmd=0x8178550"..., 34) = 34
1739  close(3)                          = 0
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/aloadC0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/snd/controlC1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/aloadC1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
1739  write(2, "aplay: device_list:270: ", 24) = 24
1739  write(2, "no soundcards found...", 22) = 22
1739  write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
1739  futex(0x4096e0ac, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
1739  exit_group(0)                     = ?
```

I'm not sure what is inhibiting me from using the sound card, can someone give me some pointers how to get it running or if it is not possible why it is not possible?

Comment: What does `ls /dev/snd` show inside the virtual machine?

Comment: You should check whether ALSA on the raspberry pi (the kernel) is compatible with the ALSA libs in the chroot. You should start with a x86 chroot system that has the same version as the main armhf debian on your RPI. If that works it is probably due to a library incompatibility. In that case you probably need a fully emulated virtual machine with a secound Linux kernel.

Comment: @Keinstein thx for suggestion, both arm and x86 return 
`controlC0  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1p  seq  timer` 
Also I'm using stretch in both environments and ALSA lib is the same 
`Driver version:     k4.9.59-v7
Library version:    1.1.3
Utilities version:  1.1.3` unless I misunderstood your comment

Comment: It could also be a byteorder issue. I don't know how qemu handles this.

Comment: ARM processors can support BE or LE. At least some of them.

Comment: I thought about it, however I believe that it works as expected since I can execute files. Only thing I can think of regarding BE/LE is if the opened `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/snd/controlC0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3` is writing in wrong order and getting rejected.